# Virtual addresses in Dump

Tags: dump, decompiling, xxd, radare2

Why are the virtual addresses in the dumpfiles different, when I use XDD and Radare2?

[Radare2-dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR54O.png)

[Xdd-dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJiXf.png)

The first image shows the Radare2-dump, the second one the xdd-dump. The addresses are not completely different. 
The xdd is:
    `000007b0` 
The radare2 is:
    `0x004007b0`

Why is there a offset of `0x00400000`?

Edit: I am working on Linux.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tools you mention, but the default load address for an application (on Windows, at least) is 0x400000, so it appears that one tool shows the actual address whereas the other shows an offset from the load address.